# Reshape wide data with multiple categories to tall in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset in excel that Looks like this:

```
Date   Country1-GDP   Country2-GDP  Country1-Unemp   Country2-Unemp
```

and I would like to produce a normalized dataset like this:

```
Date1   Country1_Name   Country1-GDP   Country1-Unemp
Date1   Country2_Name   Country2_GDP   Country2_Unemp
Date2   Country1_Name   Country1-GDP   Country1-Unemp
```

I would like to do this in VBA so that I can call it as a macro directly in excel after I pull my data in ..

any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: Will there always be the same number of countries? Will the columns always be the same ie Name, GDP, Unemp etc?

Comment: where form you take `CountryX_Name` column as there is nothing like that in your base dataset?

Comment: @simon1979 The number of countries can change, I have a Named Range that lists the countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure to break you problem into smaller problems:

**Find the sheet layout**

Identify the number of countries (so you know where the different data ranges are)

**Country 1 as basis for the rest**

Collect the country 1 columns and add the Country name column for it (use .xlEnd commands to apply it to the right amount of cells, or .OFFSET compared to the date column).

We need to have the country name for this. I guess the country name is in the column titles (followed by -GDP, -UnEmp, etc, so you can easily just get it from the -GDP column, by something like =LEFT(Range.Value2;LEN(Range.Value2)-4), which takes the last 4 charancters off. Keep this as a local variable.

**Keep a copy of the Date range (column A:A) for reuse**

We will store a copy of the range of Dates as we will use that for every other country to paste under the dates in column A:A

**Loop through the remaining countries, using the layout in place from country 1**

Now we start to Loop through all the countries 2 - N. Paste the stored copy of dates under column A:A (so 1 set for 1 country), Get the coutnry name (just as for country 1) and put that next to the freshly pasted dates.
And country by country pick the different Country characteristics for that country and move the data under the corresponding Country 1 columns.

**Sort your table**

Sort the data in any order you want (Date / Country in your case)

Comment: thanks much, having only one small problem with your step of 'Keep a copy of Date range for reuse'. This may seem really newb but what is the best way to create and store temp range in memory?

Comment: Create a `Range` object (`Dim rDates as Range`). Refer it to the range of dates in A2:Axxx (`Set rDates = Range(fromcell, tocell)`). I guess `fromcell` (also a `Range`) should be something like `Range("A2")` and `tocell` something like `Range("A2").End(xlDown)`.